# PDFView doesn't highlight search results

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdfview

I'm trying out PDFView and want to highlight searched words.
I was following this little [tutorial right here](https://medium.com/@jeffh2170/pdfkit-pdfview-8f2be66a4c8f) (see search paragraph).

I am getting matches for my PDF but when I set `pdfView.highlightedSelections = searchedItems` nothing happens.

Here's my code (VC extends PDFDocumentDelegate)

```
var document: PDFDocument!
var searchedItems: [PDFSelection] = []


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test3", withExtension: "pdf")
    document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
    pdfView.document = document
    pdfView.document?.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    pdfView.document?.findString("Product", withOptions: .caseInsensitive)
}

func documentDidEndDocumentFind(_ notification: Notification) {
    pdfView.highlightedSelections = nil
    pdfView.highlightedSelections = searchedItems
}

func documentDidFindMatch(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let selection = notification.userInfo?.first?.value as? PDFSelection {
        selection.color = .yellow
        searchedItems.append(selection)
        print("didFindMatch")
    }
}
```

Comment: wherer you're assgining value to searchedItems? does this method "documentDidFindMatch" called correctly?

Comment: try it like let selections = self.document.findString(searchText, withOptions: .caseInsensitive)
            pdfView.highlightedSelections = selections

Comment: U can use PDFKit to highlight ur searched items

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati yes I tried it. `documentDidFindMatch` is being called correctly. But I found the solution for myself, see my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay I figured it out for myself, by reading this thread here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93414

It seems that `highlightedSelections` doesn't work as documented. I will file a bug at Apple.

`PDFSelection` itself has an inner array of Type `PDFSelection`. With this I can add multiple selections inside one. After that I can use `pdfView.setCurrentSelection(_:animate:)` to set this nested selection array.

```
var document: PDFDocument!
var searchedItem: PDFSelection?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test3", withExtension: "pdf")
    document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
    pdfView.document = document
    pdfView.document?.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.document?.beginFindString("Product", withOptions: .caseInsensitive)        
}

func documentDidEndDocumentFind(_ notification: Notification) {
    pdfView.setCurrentSelection(searchedItem, animate: true)
}

func documentDidFindMatch(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let selection = notification.userInfo?.first?.value as? PDFSelection {
        selection.color = .yellow
        if searchedItem == nil {
            // The first found item sets the object.
            searchedItem = selection
        } else {
            // All other found selection will be nested
            searchedItem!.add(selection)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but when I open my PDDView Screen first it shows yellow colour square for few milliseconds and then searched text highlighted. Does that happen to you too?

Comment: Yeah it highlights a big random square first. I don't know why but I can live with that for know. You can file a radar for this, to help improve this new iOS framework :)

Comment: Ok, I am checking that issue, in case you find a solution please update here and comment.

Comment: And another thing, how can we clear that highlighted text? As setCurrentSelection to nil is still shows highlighting effect.

Comment: Yellow overlay doesn't appear when animation of pdf selection is turned off: `pdfView.setCurrentSelection(searchedItem, animate: false)`.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Rafal's answer, I made it work even with multiple page documents (and multiple search terms), like so. What I haven't been able to test yet is if this would work with a term spanning multiple pages:

```
   private func highlight(searchTerms: [String]?)
   {
      searchTerms?.forEach { term in
         let selections = pdfView?.document?.findString(term, withOptions: [.caseInsensitive])

         selections?.forEach { selection in
            selection.pages.forEach { page in
               let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
               highlight.endLineStyle = .square
               highlight.color = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

               page.addAnnotation(highlight)
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

The only solution that worked for me is `PDFAnnotation` with `.highlight` type:

```
let selections = pdfView?.document?.findString("PDFKit, my dear!", withOptions: [.caseInsensitive])
// Simple scenario, assuming your pdf is single-page.
guard let page = selections?.first?.pages.first else { return }

selections?.forEach({ selection in
    let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
    highlight.endLineStyle = .square
    highlight.color = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

    page.addAnnotation(highlight)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I found the bug and figured out a solution. See my answer!

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your instances to `highlightedSelections`

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //load your pdf ...
    //...

    self.youPdfView?.document.delegate = self
    self.yourPdfView?.highlightedSelections = [PDFSelection]()
    self.yourPdfView?.document?.beginFindString("foo", withOptions: .caseInsensitive)

}

func didMatchString(_ instance: PDFSelection) {
    instance.color = .yellow
    self.pdfView?.highlightedSelections?.append(instance)
}
```